# Vuejs nuxt import only only when its in a browser

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Am trying to import Filepond when the process is a browser . Currently i have this

```
    <script>
          import * as FilePond from 'filepond'
         export default {

           components:{
               FilePond
             }
          }
     </script>
```

So what am looking forward is to change the above to only import Filepond if its a browser. I know you can check via

```
       <script>
         if(process.browser){
            ///use import here
          }
```

But in the above i cannot add `import * as Filepond from 'filepond'` directly at the if statement. How do i achieve this

Comment: If you're using the Vue adapter component note that the export is a function that creates a component. `vueFilePond(...plugins)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require).

```
 if(process.browser){
            const FilePond = require('filepond')
          }
```